# How do you create a text anchor in Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

What is the equivalent of [Ace editor anchor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=anchor) in Monaco? i.e. a floating pointer to a position in the editor that adjusts when you insert text around it.

Comment: Update: Pretty sure there isn't one, I reimplemented it from scratch